# /opt/codedeploy-agent/bin/codedeploy-agent: No such file or directory

Tags: aws-code-deploy

I have had AWS code deploy agent running successfully on my Amazon 2 Linux instance for a while. Then today I noticed that the deployments are failing. After further investigation I have found out that the code deploy agent is failing with the following error:

```
/opt/codedeploy-agent/bin/codedeploy-agent: No such file or directory
```

If I try to re-install the code deploy agent, the installation skips, since the version in the system is already up to date.

If I try to uninstall codedeploy agent with:

```
sudo yum erase codedeploy-agent
```

The installer still thinks that I have the current version installed and skips.

Any ideas how I can fix this? Is there a way to somehow remove the code deploy agent completely, so the installer will run again?

Many thanks for your help in advance,

Olli

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSM to install the CodeDeploy agent on an EC2 instance. The whole installation process is managed by AWS, and it's been pretty reliable from my experience.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/codedeploy-agent-operations-install-ssm.html